# What kind of guitar is this?

Tags: guitar

I recently bought an acoustic guitar in Venezuela but I don't know which type of acoustic it is (I bought it in a hurry).

I think it is a classical type of guitar, due to the strings (Some are made of nylon and the others are made of nylon with copper).

The photos below are lower-resolution images. Links to the full images follow.

[image: Guitar in full]

[image: Strings close-up]

[image: Soundhole/indicia close-up]

https://photos.app.goo.gl/CN7nNq3Td6nUTXhG6 (complete instrument)
https://photos.app.goo.gl/WPZBSpnvXie1dDBf7 (strings close-up)
https://photos.app.goo.gl/FQARfWAyxxeWSrvV8 (soundhole/indicia close-up)

Comment: This isn't ideally the sort of question we encourage on this site.So it will most likely be closed soon. With nylon strings, it would come in the category of 'classical' guitar. But, what difference will that make? Little point in downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

Blue. Just kidding! You're right about the type. Classical. The E and A strings look wider spaced that the others. You might check the nut and bridge about that spacing.

Comment: They said, "You have a blue guitar,
You do not play things as they are."

Comment: @DaveJacoby, thanks! I wasn't familiar with that poem. I only know Thirteen Ways of Looking at a Blackbird.

Comment: I mostly know it because Peter Case named a fantastic album _The Man with the Blue Post-Modern Fragmented Neo-Traditionalist Guitar_.

Answer (score 2):

As what the others have said as well, it's a classical guitar. Here are some notable traits for a classical acoustic guitar!:

- The 12th fret stops at the end of the body (if you count yours, the twelfth fret meets the body)! Unlike electric guitar, where the fret goes beyond the 12th to meet the body
- Often uses nylon strings or copper.

Now to get into more details---
Acoustic vs Classical guitar

- Classical guitar generally has a wider neck compared to electric. Usually it becomes slightly wider as it goes down to the body of the guitar.
- The tuning pegs lie flat to the head of the guitar- not straight like a normal acoustic guitar.
- If you check where the fret board ends, it looks like it's cut around the sound hole
  [image]

acoustic guitar doesn't have that! It's not cut around the sound hole. If you search online for normal acoustic guitars you'll probably see the end of the fret board cut straight!
So yeah :)! those are some notable differences.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical guitar. It has a typical classical guitar headstock and tuning machines, as well as the bridge.